# How to rephrase a long comprative sentence

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, comparative, academic-writing

I am trying to state a comparative argument in a long sentence for an academic paper. I don't want to split it. Is there any way for shortening it? Is it always necessary to use "those of the" "that of the" in these kinds of comparative sentences?

**Sentence:**

"The Tarim Basin presents transitional values between those of the Tibet and the Yangtze, reflecting either a transitional state of its crust between those of the Tibet and Yangtze or the coexistence of these two states"

Comment: You are comparing the Tibet and the Yangtze?  Are you speaking of rivers, basins, or something else?  Is *the Tibet* a river?  I think you can probably drop *those of the* but I'm not entirely sure what is being said.

Comment: You seem to be using "values" and "states" as synonyms, and it isn't clear what you are talking about.

Comment: @EllieK I am comparing the Tarim (Transitional values) with the Tibet (high values) and Yangtze (low values) Basins, and am saying that these observations infer that the crust state of the Tarim Basin should be a transient state between the other two (Yangtze and Tibet). 
In other words, I am trying to infer the crust state from the values of those three regions.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty They are two different things. I am trying to infer the crust states from the values of those three regions.

Comment: @Esi What do you mean by *values*?

Comment: I think I am almost there in understanding what you want to say.  But what do you mean by "the coexistence of these two states"?  How can one state represent a coexistence of two other states?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "Values" refer to the velocity values in the preceding sentences.

Comment: @Vegawatcher  In "the coexistence of these two states", I meant the state is like a mosaic state of those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a question of simplification and “de-cluttering” rather than one of phrasing. You simply need to omit a great many words. My suggestion:

> The Tarim Basin presents values between those of the Tibet and Yangtze, reflecting either its crust’s transitional state (between those of the Tibet and Yangtze) or the coexistence of these two states.

For clarity, you need to specify what “these two states” refers to; otherwise, there isn’t really a way to avoid using the phrase “those of.” What you can do, however, is simplify everything else around it to make the flow of ideas more concise.